# How to optimize an inside while loop searching?

Tags: perl

For once again I will need your help!

have a file tab separated like that:

```
chr10.10.2      scaffold1116    94.92   394     13      1       16      409     10474   10860   4.1e-201        697.0
chr10.10.2      scaffold1116    100.00  14      0       0       1       14      10453      10466   1.9e+01 27.0
…………………………
```

and another file like that:

```
chr10.10.1      283
chr10.10.2      409
chr10.10.3      572
chr10.10.4      248
chr10.10.5      143
…………………………
```

I want to keep some specific lines from the first file, based on the numbers of the second one.

For example, if I have to keep the line with the "chr10.10.2", I have to check the number that "chr10.10.2" has at the second file.
I wrote a script, but due to these two files are quite large it takes a lot of time.
(For each line of the first file it searches all the lines of the second one).
Is there any way to search the second file with a more efficient way?

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $blat_out = $ARGV[0];
my $sizes    = $ARGV[1];

#Cheking the output of "HCEs Vs Genomes" alignments (blat) based on the sizes of the HCEs....

open my $blat_file, $blat_out or die "Could not open $blat_out: $!";
while ( my $line = <$blat_file> ) {
    chomp $line;
    # while( my $size_line = <$size_file>)  {
    if ( $line =~ m/^chr/ ) {
        my @lines = split( '\t', $line );
        #my @size_lines = split('\t', $size_line);
        my $hce        = $lines[0];
        #print "$hce\n";
        my $scaf       = $lines[1];
        my $persent    = $lines[2];
        my $al_length  = $lines[3];
        my $hce_start  = $lines[6];
        my $hce_end    = $lines[7];
        my $scaf_start = $lines[8];
        my $scaf_end   = $lines[9];
        my $score      = $lines[10];
        open my $size_file, $sizes or die "Could not open $sizes: $!";

        while ( my $size_line = <$size_file> ) {
            chomp $size_line;
            my @size_lines = split( '\t', $size_line );
            my $hce_name   = $size_lines[0];
            my $hce_size   = $size_lines[1];
            #print "$hce_size\n";

            if ( $hce eq $hce_name ) {
                my $al_ratio = $al_length / $hce_size;
                if ( ( $persent >= 98 ) && ( $al_ratio >= 0.9 ) ) {
                    print "$line\n";    #print only the lines that satisfies the previous criteria
                }

            }
        }
        #close $size_file;
    }
}
```

Thank you very much in advance,
Vasilis.

Comment: Yes, make a hash out of second file, though it isn't clear what you want to do with it.

Comment: Read in and store the contents of `size_file` - at the moment, you've got the open/parse inside the while loop that reads the blat file, which means it will execute for every line of the blat file. It's no wonder the script is running slowly!

Comment: Probable bug:  You `split` on the single quoted `'\t'`.  That is probably not going to do what you want.  You likely want the double quoted `"\t"`

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to store **$size_file** in memory (hash) so you won't need to open it for each row of **$blat_file**. That's I/0 heavy.

You can create your own script to do that or use the **[File::Slurp](http://search.cpan.org/~uri/File-Slurp-9999.19/lib/File/Slurp.pm)** module.

**Bonus:** You can also use the [Text::CSV_XS](http://search.cpan.org/~hmbrand/Text-CSV_XS-1.11/CSV_XS.pm#Reading_a_CSV_file_line_by_line) module for faster parsing, with tab as the delimiter instead of comma.

Also, this is unrelated but an FYI, you can transform these lines:

```
my $hce        = $lines[0];
my $scaf       = $lines[1];
my $persent    = $lines[2];
my $al_length  = $lines[3];
my $hce_start  = $lines[6];
my $hce_end    = $lines[7];
my $scaf_start = $lines[8];
my $scaf_end   = $lines[9];
my $score      = $lines[10];
```

into:

```
my ($hce, $scaf, $persent, $al_length, undef, undef, $hce_start, $hce_end, $scaf_start, $scaf_end, $score) = @lines;
```

Answer (score 2):

How about using a hash that stores the second file:

```
# Build hash of hce_name => hce_size
my %size = do {
    open my $fh, '<', $sizes or die "Could not open $sizes: $!";
    map { chomp; split "\t", $_, 2 } <$fh>;
};

open my $blat_file, '<', $blat_out or die "Could not open $blat_out: $!";
while ( my $line = <$blat_file> ) {
    chomp $line;

    next if $line !~ m/^chr/;

    my @fields     = split "\t", $line;
    my $hce        = $fields[0];
    my $scaf       = $fields[1];
    my $persent    = $fields[2];
    my $al_length  = $fields[3];
    my $hce_start  = $fields[6];
    my $hce_end    = $fields[7];
    my $scaf_start = $fields[8];
    my $scaf_end   = $fields[9];
    my $score      = $fields[10];

    next if !exists $size{$hce};

    my $al_ratio = $al_length / $size{$hce};
    if ( $persent >= 98 && $al_ratio >= 0.9 ) {
        print "$line\n";    #print only the lines that satisfies the previous criteria
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If both of your files are very large, then don't use a hash table. Use sorting.

First, sort both files based on the first column:

```
$ sort -k 1,1 first.tsv > first.sorted
$ sort -k 1,1 second.tsv > second.sorted
```

Then walk through the first and second files line by line, looking for matches between the two.

When there are matches, print them — otherwise, walk through either the first or second file, depending on a string comparison result:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $firstFn = "first.sorted";
my $secondFn = "second.sorted";
open my $firstFh, "<", $firstFn or die "could not open first file\n";
open my $secondFh, "<", $secondFn or die "could not open second file\n";
my $firstLine = <$firstFh>;
chomp $firstLine;
my @firstElems = split("\t", $firstLine);
my $firstChr = $firstElems[0];
while (<$secondFh>) {
    chomp;
    my ($secondChr, $secondNum) = split("\t", $_);

    #
    # Test *chr string equality: 
    #
    #  1. If secondChr is less than ("lt") firstChr, then we
    #     retrieve the next secondChr.
    #
    #  2. If secondChr is the same as ("eq") firstChr, then we 
    #     print out the first file's current line and retrieve the 
    #     next line from the first file, then re-test.
    #
    #  3. If secondChr is greater than ("gt") firstChr, then we
    #     retrieve the next line from the first file until there
    #     is a match.
    #

    if ($secondChr lt $firstChr) {
        next;
    }
    while ($secondChr eq $firstChr) {
        print STDOUT "$firstLine\n";
        $firstLine = <$firstFh>;
        chomp $firstLine;
        @firstElems = split("\t", $firstLine);
        $firstChr = $firstElems[0];
    }
    while ($secondChr gt $firstChr) {
        $firstLine = <$firstFh>;
        chomp $firstLine;
        @firstElems = split("\t", $firstLine);
        $firstChr = $firstElems[0];
        while ($secondChr eq $firstChr) {
            print STDOUT "$firstLine\n";
            $firstLine = <$firstFh>;
            chomp $firstLine;
            @firstElems = split("\t", $firstLine);
            $firstChr = $firstElems[0];
        }
    }
}
close $secondFh;
close $firstFh;
```

This is untested, but I think it should work (or at least the explanation will get you close).

The advantage of this approach over using hash tables is that you only need enough memory to store two lines, one from each file. Unless your lines are also very long, your memory overhead is now practically a non-issue. If you have very large files, this could be an important advantage.

The disadvantage is the up-front time cost of sorting two (large) files. But if one of the files does not change, some of the sort time can be amortized quickly if you do frequent lookups between the two files.

Comment: Its a very elegant solution (thank you) but the blat_file (first_file) has inside some strange lines and it cant be sorted unfortunately.

Comment: If memory is your bottleneck, perhaps restructure your BLAT file so that you can apply sorting tricks and do your query step. Then take the result and "un"-structure it to return to the original format.